# How to load CSV from a text file to structure in C properly?

Tags: c, file, csv, struct

I have a file of words and numbers separated with "|" and I need to load them into a struct so I can use them later on. It's a file of countries, their currencies and rate of exchange and I need to break them into a structure, then work with them. Basically I need to create a C currency exchange program.

Data in the file look like this:

```
country|currency|quantity|code|rate of exchange
Canada|dollar|1|CAD|19,430
```

This is what the structure looks like `(FILE * currencies = fopen("denni_kurz.txt", "r"))`:

```
struct data
{
    char buffer[100];
    char country[40];
    char nameofcurrency[20];
    int quantity;
    char code[5];
    float exchangerate;
}currency[40];
```

Then i have a loop to load all of them:

```
while (!feof(currencies))
{

}
```

The problem here is that i read documentation but it's just not working for me.
Could anyone give me a hint on how to load them where they belong?

Comment: `while (!feof(currencies))` bad idea.

Comment: Is "buffer" not used? I don't understand the exchangerate of 19,430. Shouldn't it be something like 1.14? Or is comma used as decimal point?

Comment: It is a decimal point, yes. I thought i would read the whole thing,  load into buffer and then break it down into smaller pieces using strtok, but it's not working for me, so i'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You can use sscanf function to load the CSV file. by default sscanf() will take space as delimiter. you can specify | in sscanf and store it in the structure.
first get the lines from the csv file using fgets and store it in a array.
Then get the lines from the array and store in the structure.

```
eg:        while(fgets(array,BUFSIZ,fp) != NULL)
             sscanf(array," %d | %s | %s | %d | %d | %s | %f | %[0-9]s",&account[i].customer_id,account[i].name,account[i].address,&account[i].account_number,&account[i].age,account[i].sex,&account[i].balance_amount,account[i].mobile_number);
```

Then if you print the structure variable the corresponding values will be printed.

```
printf("id:%d\n name:%s\n address:%s\n account number:%d\n age:%d\n sex:%s\n balance:%f\n mobile:%s\n",account[j].customer_id,account[j].name,account[j].address,account[j].account_number,account[j].age,account[j].sex,account[j].balance_amount,account[j].mobile_number);
```

Comment: Tried this but it doesn't really work, i'm getting some data and then a lot of random symbols.

Comment: I have used sscanf for uploading a csv file. and the file has uploaded. that why I suggested you to use. can you post the snippet which you have used?

Answer (score 0):

If  nothing helps, you can always revert to stupid character processing, such as:

```
struct data *p= currency;
while (fgets(p->buffer,100, currencies)) {
    char *cp1= p->buffer;
    char *cp2= p->buffer;
    while (*cp2!='|') cp2++;
    strncpy(p->country, cp1, cp2-cp1); p->country[cp2-cp1]='\0';
    cp2++; cp1=cp2; 
    // etc....
    p++;    // next line
}
```

Of course you still need to add the appropriate checks (not processing past end of line, not end of currency array, not country name too long, not...)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, i got it working through strncpy, strtok, atoi and atof.